# Cannot create my own test certificate authority that Firefox will accept

Tags: java, tomcat, x509, certificate

I am following [these steps](http://www.tc.umn.edu/%7Ebrams006/selfsign.html) to go though creating a basic CA and a server certificate that has been signed by the CA. I imported the CA cert into cacerts in the JDK and created a single entry JKS keystore containing the server's certificate. I get this error in Firefox:

> Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

Comment: What is the result if you put your certificate to a apache Webserver? You could set the apache in front of tomcat.

Comment: The error code reads to me that you have not setup a suitable suite of ciphers available that both ends can agree on.  If you are on linux you can use "openssl s_client -connect 1.2.3.4:443 -showcerts" to get diagnostic information about what is happening (please paste into question). Which JVM do you use? For example Java5 from Sun did not support "High Grade encryption" due to export out of the US.  It would not supprise me that a modern browser will refuse low-grade encrption these days.  This circumstance would create a mismatch that may result in the error you are seeing.